# Prove a certain homomorphism in the category of rings is an epimorphism

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

I've been reading the Queen Mary Note of Maurice Auslander 's paper Representation dimension of artin algebras. However I met some difficulties that are not so relevant to the topic. The following is such one.

On page six he describes the image of a morphism between two commutative rings in the category of rings with identities.

Let R and T be commutative rings and $f:R\rightarrow T$ a ring homomorphism. Let $f(R)=S$. We have $f_1:T\rightarrow T\otimes_ST$ defined by $f_1(t)=1\otimes t$ and $f_2(t)=t\otimes 1$.

Let $T'=\{t\in T| f_1(t)=f_2(t)\}$. Clearly $T'$ contains S, so that $f$ maps $R$ into $T'$. Prove that the inclusion map $S\rightarrow T'$ is an epimorphism in the category of rings and the inclusion map $T'\rightarrow T$ is a strong monomorphism.

I tried to use the notion dominion and pushout to prove the epimorphism part but failed. 
[image]

Comment: Concerning the second part: Regular monomorphisms are strong. And $T' \to T$ is the equalizer of $f_1,f_2$.

Comment: I am not confident that $S \to T'$ is always an epimorphism of comm. rings. Notice that $T'$ is the dominion aka epicenter of $S \hookrightarrow T$, whose elements have a matrix-like representation (see P. Mazet, Characterization des epimorphismes par generators and relateurs, Seminaire Samuel; or http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VY), but these matrices have coefficients in $T$, not necessarily in $T'$. Also, in the literature on epimorphisms of commutative rings (which I am quite familiar with) I cannot find the statement that $S \to T'$ is an epimorphism.

Comment: @HeinrichD I will post this paper if it helps

Comment: If you mean a link to Auslander's paper, this would be appreciated. I could not find it online.

Comment: @HeinrichD I find the paper through my university's data base, and I could not find it online either

Comment: I would really look for counterexamples. Notice that many mathematicians write things down because they want them to be true, not necessarily because they have found a proof. This is the sad reality.

Comment: If $\mathbf{CRing}^\mathrm{op}$ were a regular category, then the construction of $T'$ is precisely the usual construction of the image in a regular category as the coequalizer of the kernel pair (in $\mathbf{CRing}^\mathrm{op}$). I imagine finding a counterexample would boil down to finding a counterexample proving $\mathbf{CRing}^\mathrm{op}$ is not regular. (ping @HeinrichD)

Comment: The category of affine schemes is not regular, for sure.

Comment: This is old, but I think the answer I posted a few days ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4439437/742) proves that it is not necessarily an epimorphism. @HeinrichD would you agree?

Answer (score 0):

The asserted claim is incorrect: the inclusion map $S\to T'$ need not be an epimorphism.

Note that there are categories of algebras (even varieties) where some subalgebras are properly contained in their dominion, but where epimorphisms are nonetheless surjective, so this claim would not provable from with a categorical approach: it isn't true even in varities of algebras.

But it is also not true in the case of commutative rings with $1$. I [recently constructed a counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4439437/742), not realizing the question has been asked here before.

Explicitly, let $T=\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]$, and let $S=\mathbb{Z}[xy,y,yz]$. Then $T'=\mathbb{Z}+yT$. Indeed, if $x^ay^bz^c$ is any monomial divisible  by $y$ ($b\gt 0$) which lies in $T'$, then so does $x^{a+1}y^bz^c$: if $f,g\colon T\to \mathfrak{T}$ are homomorphisms with $f|_S=f|_S$, then
$$\begin{align*}
f(x^{a+1}y^bz^c) &= f(x(x^ay^bz^c))\\
&=f(x)f(x^ay^bz^c)\\
&= f(x)g(x^ay^bz^c)\\
&= f(x)g(y)g(x^ay^{b-1}z^c)\\
&= f(x)f(y)g(x^ay^{b-1}z^c)\\
&= f(xy)g(x^ay^{b-1}z^c)\\
&= g(xy)g(x^ay^{b-1}z^c)\\
&= g(x^{a+1}y^bz^c).
\end{align*}$$
A symmetric argument shows that if $x^ay^bz^c\in T'$ with $b\gt 0$, then $x^ay^bz^{c+1}\in T'$. Thus, every monomial divisible by $y$ lies in $T'$. Conversely, if $p(x,y,z)\notin \mathbb{Z}+yT$. then the maps $T\to T$ that maps $x\mapsto x$, $z\mapsto z$ and $y\mapsto 0$, and the one that maps $x,y,z\mapsto 0$ agree on $S$, but disagree on $p(x,y,z)$.

To show that the inclusion $S\to T'$ is not an epimorphism it suffices to show that there exist a commutative ring with $1$, $\mathfrak{T}$, and two morphism $T'\to \mathfrak{T}$ that agree on $S$ but not on all of $T'$. For example,
$$ \mathfrak{T} = \mathbb{Z}[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2),$$
the ring of dual numbers. Let $f,g\colon T'\to \mathfrak{T}$
be the morphisms defined by sending $xy$, $y$, and $yz$ to $\epsilon$; $f$ sends $xyz$ to $\epsilon$ and $g$ sends it to $0$. And both $f$ and $g$ send every other monomial to $0$. It is not hard to verify these maps are multiplicative, but since they disagree on $xyz$, the inclusion $S\to T'$ is not an epimorphism.